# Stop echo and consume all user input in Bash

Tags: bash, echo, stty, tput

#### TARGET

Until some sub-task in script completes its job:

- stop echo;
- disable cursor;
- consume all user input;
- do not block interrupts (Ctrl+C, etc.).

#### WHAT HAVE DONE

For now, using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26137110/disabling-user-input-during-an-infinite-loop-in-bash), I create few functions for that, here they are:

```
function hide_input()
{
  if [ -t 0 ]; then
    stty -echo -icanon time 0 min 0
  fi
}

function reset_input()
{
  if [ -t 0 ]; then
    stty sane
  fi
}

function stop_interactive()
{
  trap reset_input EXIT
  trap hide_input CONT
  hide_input
  tput civis
}

function start_interactive()
{
  tput cnorm
  reset_input
}

function consume_input()
{
  local line
  while read line; do line=''; done
}
```

And here is the way they are used:

```
echo "Warn the user: the job will be started."
read -p "Continue? [yes/no] > "
if [ "$REPLY" == "yes" ]; then
  stop_interactive  # <== from here all input should be rejected
  echo "Notify the user: job starting..."

  # << ------ here goes some long job with output to terminal ------>

  echo "Notify the user: job done!"
  consume_input # <== here I trying to get all user input and put nowhere
  start_interactive # <== from here restore normal operation
else
  echo "Aborted!"
  exit 0
fi
```

#### THE PROBLEM

The problem is: current 'solution' does not work. When I press keys during long running job they appears on the screen, and pressing 'Enter' ruins all output with cursor movements. Furthermore, after 'start_interactive' function call all input appears on the terminal screen.

What is the right solution for this task?

#### SOLUTION

Final working solution is:

```
function hide_input()
{
  if [ -t 0 ]; then
    stty -echo -icanon time 0 min 0
  fi
}

function reset_input()
{
  if [ -t 0 ]; then
    stty sane
  fi
}

function consume_input()
{
  local line
  while read line; do line=''; done
}

function stop_interactive()
{
  trap reset_input EXIT
  trap hide_input CONT
  hide_input
  tput civis
}

function start_interactive()
{
  consume_input
  trap - EXIT
  trap - CONT
  tput cnorm
  reset_input
}

echo "Warn the user: the job will be started."
read -p "Continue? [yes/no] > "
if [ "$REPLY" == "yes" ]; then
  stop_interactive
  echo "Notify the user: job starting..."
  do_the_job &
  pid=$!
  while ps $pid > /dev/null ; do
    consume_input
  done
  echo "Notify the user: job done!"
  start_interactive
else
  echo "Aborted!"
  exit 0
fi
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based in your question, there are many questions "why" if I look at your code. If you do not want to change the behavior of ^C etc., then don't use traps. All your functions test whether the file descriptor 0 is a terminal. Do you plan to use the script in a pipe? Also, your consuming of user input will continue until end-of-file, so the script may never end.

Based on your question, I would write something like this:

```
echo "Warn the user: the job will be started."
read -p "Continue? [yes/no] > "
if [ "$REPLY" == "yes" ]; then
    stty -echo
    echo "Notify the user: job starting..."
    program_to_execute &
    pid=$!
    while ps $pid > /dev/null ; do
        read -t 1 line
    done
    echo "Notify the user: job done!"
else
    echo "Aborted!"
fi
stty sane
```

Comment: it's strange, but I got a error when put 'stty -echo' to script:
stty: 'standard input': Inappropriate ioctl for device
when I run it from terminal all works fine, just when inside script

Comment: thank you for background job suggestion, it will be useful to run input consumer in main job

Comment: scrip will not freeze, because -icanon sets zero read timeout

Comment: the problem was that I piping 'yes' answer to the script!

Comment: That makes sense; `[ -t 0 ]` will fail and your `stty`s never get executed.